# Does ASP.net MVC 4 have some standardized way of referring to relative paths in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm working on an ASP.net MVC application.  One thing that I really like about ASP.net MVC is the way that it allows you to refer to relative paths in server-side code.  I was wondering if there is some standardized way of doing this in client-side code.

I have a way of doing this.  I write the following in my layout page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ApplicationPath = '@Url.Content("~/")';                
</script>
```

Making this the first script in my layout page, I can refer to relative paths from any .js file using the `ApplicationPath` variable.  This seems to work well, but I'm left wondering if there is some built-in way of working with relative paths in JavaScript.  This works well for me, but someone else might use a different convention.

Does ASP.net MVC 4 have some standardized way of referring to relative paths in JavaScript?

Comment: I was also looking for a solution. Did you ever find a cleaner way? What do you think about using a cookie and reading the cookie in the javascript so that there wouldn't be a need for a separate script?

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this in my masterpage header:

```
<script type="text/javscript">
    var conf = { baseUrl: '<%=VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/")%>' };
</script>
```

Then, anywhere else in js you can just use:

```
var fullUrl = conf.baseUrl + '/somePath';
```

Also, you can always get the base domain in JS using:

```
var baseUrl = window.location.hostname;
```

Comment: This is not the answer I'm looking for.  Your answer is very similar to what I've proposed here.  What I want to know is whether or not the framework has some built-in mechanism for handling this.

Comment: If the .NET framework has a way of altering a client browser's implementation of javascript?

Comment: ASP.net does create some variables and functions in JavaScript that allow you to reference some server-side things.  __doPostBack is probably the best-known of these.  I was wondering if there might be some other function or variable created by the framework I could refer to and count on it being there.